# using AOP in web context and affection on performance

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications, aop

I have a web application running most of my services through web services. 
first i want to know how much degradation in performance would take place using AOP in web context for example 
if i can handle 200 request/second without AOP, what would be the result with it (having simple logging and authorization)

Is there any great AOP framework available out there for .NET ? 
Is it a better idea to use Proxy web services (implementing authorization, logging , ... in proxy) for gaining the better performance or the overhead of using AOP is negligible and its advantages worth performance degradation.

WHATS the best replacement for AOP in .net framework ?

Comment: i want to control authorization create some logging, enable or disable web services i need, exception handling, caching and many more common tasks that should perform when each web service is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best AOP framework I know of for .Net is PostSharp. It's really slick, easy to use, and it doesn't affect run-time performace in any way bad, since all weaving takes place at compile time (compile times will grow a bit due to this, but it's definitly manageble). The only thing that happens is that your aspects get weaved in as methods, so performance-wise there's no difference between writing your logging code the classical way, to putting them in aspects when using PostSharp.

Find it over at the [SharpCrafters website](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).

Comment: you say that with PostSharp i can get the same performance when writing in classical way ? any benchmark ?

Comment: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/introducing-postsharp-2-0-2-amazing-runtime-performance-enhancements.aspx